# Bind event to document>element and addEventListener to element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Which is the logical/programming difference? I was answering to a duplicated question so I tried to modify one of those repetive answers with a new approach (from my point of view, since it looks longer):

```
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON"),
        t = document.createTextNode("123");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    btn.setAttribute("class", "xyz");
    btn.setAttribute("value", "s" + i);
    btn.appendChild(t);

    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    $(document).bind('click', btn, function () {
    //btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert(this.value);
    });
}
```

My "problem" is that `btn.addEventListener('click', function(){})` works correctly: just one alert pop-up and binds to the created element and `$(document).bind('click', btn,function(){..})` triggers the alert 11 times and doesn't bind to the just created element.
Probably is a simple, stupid and useless question, but I'm pretty cusrios.
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/w3x1qp42/1/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The second option (`btn` in your case) is expected to be the CSS selector not an DOM node.

So you can do it like this

```
$(document).bind('click', 'button.xyz', function () {
//btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).bind('click', btn, function () {
```

`btn` here is supposed to be a selector, I don't think it accepts an element.
`bind` is depreciated, you should use `on` instead

Just do `$(btn).on('click', function() {`

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
$(btn).bind('click', function () {
         alert($(this).attr("value"));
});
```